# How to create "multi-level" condition lists in Hybris Generic Search Query?

Tags: sql, sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to do something like this:

```
Select * 
From Product
Where (... OR ...) AND ... AND ...;
```

I have a working GenericSearchQuery for the 1st part "(... OR ...)", but not the second (the part after the closing parenthesis).
As I noticed, the GenericQuery needs a single list of GenericConditions with one single operator stored for every GenericConditons in the list. 
My problem is that I cannot figure out how to create two different condition lists with a specified operator between them.

Comment: Why not use sp_executesql ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8bc36ba986691014b48be171221d1f4f.html

If you want to search attributes from different tables you have to do a Join over it